check python code location after pip installl
I am using setuptools to manage my python project,
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="falcon",
    version="1.0.0",
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=open("./requirements.txt").readlines(),
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "falcon-extract = xxxx.yyyy.main:main",
        ]
    },
)


when I run the following command to install packages
pip install -e .

I am wondering where the package is installed, and where the console command "falcon-extract" is installed.
(1) Suppose I have a virtual environment, for example, ~/venv/my-project, where is the package installed? and where is console command "falcon-extract" installed?
(2) Suppose I am using MacOS, I don't create virtual environment, when I run "pip install -e .", where is the package installed? and where is console command "falcon-extract" installed?
(3) In the installed folder, does it install source code ? Could I view these source code?
